# Validate backend password in shopware 6

Tags: validation, passwords, backend, shopware, shopware6

I need to make sure that passwords in the backend are compliant with a certain standard (at least seven characters, muts have numeric and alphabetic characters).

There are a lot of plugins that deal with it but for the frontend customers, I need it for backend users.

How can this be done, is there an event I can use to add validation rules or do I need to decorate some service instead? Which one?

Answer (score 4):

You can listen to the event "\Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Validation\PreWriteValidationEvent" and add an exception when its miss match your conditions.

This event is fired on all entities, so check the entity before.
On Administration side, you can react to the backend error and show an error message with overriding the component